# Connecting BigQuery and Google Sheet case sensitive parameter issue

Tags: google-bigquery

Would be great if someone know how to deal with the (?i) parameter when using google sheet variable connected to BigQuery:

REGEXP_CONTAINS(event_label, (?i)@BANNERS) don't work

REGEXP_CONTAINS(event_label, @BANNERS) works but is case sensitive

REGEXP_CONTAINS(event_label, '(?i)label x') is not case sensitive and works !

In my case @BANNERS refers to a cell into my Google sheet

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for an alternative for (?i) I believe this flag does make matches for your regex case insensitive.

Can you try:

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(event_label, @BANNERS[a-bA-B].*)
```

(apologies not sure what you are trying to match or expected results)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but BigQuery returns error message "BigQuery error: Syntax error: Unexpected "*" at [4:51]" Finally I found the solution here: https://devcodef1.com/news/1181290/bigquery-googlesheets-case-sensitive-parameter-issue. I replaced with "REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(event_label), LOWER((@BANNERS)))" It was just question to convert to lower case at both side because Google sheet is not case sensitive and BigQuery is case sensitive.